# How to minimize the impact of WSL2 performance issues in projects that use both Windows and Linux applications?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm a big fan of being able to use Linux on my Windows machine, but when looking at the differences between WSL 1 and 2, there is one [potentially?] glaring issue for my particular case:

> [...] the WSL 2
> architecture outperforms WSL 1 in several ways, with the exception of
> performance across OS file systems, which can be addressed by storing
> your project files on the same operating system as the tools you are
> running to work on the project.

[[ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions)]

I am working with both MATLAB (a windows app with no WSL support yet) and Python (installed for WSL), so I'm not sure if it's optimal to use WSL2 when I have codebases and databases that use both languages (and hence both operating systems). Would I save such projects in a Linux directory or a Windows one?

I've just downgraded to WSL1 to avoid this headache for the time being, but was wondering if there were solutions for situations like this on WSL2.

Comment: I see people are downvoting answers here, so this is a comment : If your aim is better integration of WSL with Windows - stay with WSL1. If your aim is using graphical Linux apps - go to Windows 11 with WSL2. But on Windows 10 I don't think the performance issue is such a big deal.

Comment: You're welcome to rephrase and focus your question to get you a single, practical question that can be answered. We want good questions, and free use of the EDIT button is strongly encouraged to achieve that end.

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  I know that it can sometimes be tricky to navigate some of the policies here (especially for new users), but two pointers as far as your question -- First, questions that invite "opinion-based" responses are off-topic, and the *"is it worth it"* in your title almost certainly drew some votes-to-close.  I've edited the title to still keep your meaning (and match the question body a bit more closely), but remove the "opinion" wording.